# the widget does not close/quit with the main window

Tags: python, pyqt4

I have the following python code where the main window has a widget using PyQt4

```
import os
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, Qt


class Widget(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self):
        super(FringeFrame, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.showFullScreen()

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.widget = Widget()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mywin = MainWindow()
    mywin.show()
    sys.quit(app.exec_ ())    


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

the issue here is that i want widget and mywin to have their own window, it works that way, but when I close mywin, the widget is not closed with mywin. 
How should i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just override the `QMainWindow`'s [`closeEvent`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#closeEvent):

```
class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.widget = Widget()

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.widget.close()
```